# PHP multidimensional array, each number as an array in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a database with the following information:

```
    | ID | Name | Number |
    +----+------+--------+ 
    | 1  |  aaa |   1    |
    | 2  |  bbb |   1    |
    | 3  |  ccc |   2    |
    | 4  |  ddd |   2    |
```

and so on.....

What I want is to make an array like this:

```
    $array[1] = array ('aaa','bbb');
    $array[2] = array ('ccc','ddd');
```

And so on......

How do I achieve that, with a loop?

This is what I got so far:

```
while ($array = $query_res->fetch_assoc()) {
     $final_array[$array['Number']] = array ($array['Name']);
}
print_r($final_array);
```

This isn't working. I think I should use `array_merge` but can't figure out how to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
while ($array = $query_res->fetch_assoc()) {
     $final_array[$array['Number']][] = $array['Name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If $array is really an array an contains the keys ID,Number and Name

```
   $final_array = array();
   while ($array = $query_res->fetch_assoc()) {
       $final_array[$array['Number']][] = array ($array['Name']);
   }
```

and then print_r ....

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if an element with the key exists, if yes, push the new value into the array, if not create a new array:

```
while ($array = $query_res->fetch_assoc()) {
     if(isset($final_array[$array['Number']]){
         $final_array[$array['Number']][] = $array['Name'];
     }else{
         $final_array[$array['Number']] = array ($array['Name']);
     }
}
print_r($final_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
SELECT `Number`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(`Name`)) as `Name` FROM `table`
```

You will get a response like:

Number=1, Name=aaa,bbb
   Number=2, Name=ccc,ddd

Then do something like

```
while ($array = $query_res->fetch_assoc()) {
     $final_array[$array['Number']] = explode(',' $array['Name']);
}
print_r($final_array);
```